# session_start() not working on browser

Tags: php, session-variables

I am working on a login script, however since I do not have write permissions on the /tmp folder I made another one and set the session.dave_path to the new folder.

I've been testing the script on the terminal and the folder gets a new entry, however when I run the scrip on the browsers the script fails and there is no new entry to the new tmp folder.

Now, I've tested the new path by outputing the new path and it gives me the right thing (of course this should be true since the script works on the terminal)

Here is how I start the script:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', $path);
session_start();
```

is there any reason why this should work on the terminal and not on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a permissions issue. When you run the file on the command line it is running as your user. When you access the file via the browser it is running as the web server user (i.e. apache). Try giving the web server write permissions on the folder you created and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: You might want to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: this solution worked for me too! MariaH please mark this as the answer and give some credit to Ian!

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be obvious but do you have the `session_start()` before the `<html>` tage at the top?

Comment: no, there is no html tags since the script only redirects to a new page if login was successful

Comment: if it is an html page it needs to have the html tag.